# Solr 6.1.0: Can't specify exponent for BlendedInfixLookupFactory Suggester

Tags: solr, lucene

How do you specify the exponent configuration variable for the BlendedInfixLookupFactory Suggester when using blenderType = position_reciprocal in Solr 6.1.0?

I'm relatively new to using Solr, but I've successfully gotten a suggester up and running. I'm trying to use the BlendedInfixLookupFactory, but can't figure out how to specify the exponent configuration variable.

The relevant location in my solrconfig.xml file:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SuggestComponent" name="suggest">
 <lst name="suggester">
   <str name="name">name</str>
   <str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
   <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
   <str name="field">field</str>
   <str name="weightField">weightField</str>
   <str name="contextField">contextField</str>
   <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_en</str>
   <str name="blenderType">position_reciprocal</str>
   <double name="exponent">2.0</double>
 </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Looking at the weights returned from my suggester it looks like the exponent being used is 1.0, despite the default being listed as 2.0.

Example data:

Initial weight = 540

Position = 5

Final weight = 90.

So if I solve for the exponent, I get 1.0.

The equation is:
 FinalWeight = InitialWeight * ( 1 / (1 + Position)^Exp)

90 = 540 * ( 1 / (1 + 5)^Exp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using the incorrect blenderType. There exists a third option called "position_exponential_reciprocal" which allows the use of the exponent option. This option is not listed in the documentation but can be found in the source code, which is hosted on GitHub.

I will leave this question intact in case someone else makes the same mistake I do.